# SwiftUI List inside ZStack inside NavigationView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am building a screen with list and custom full screen background color. On the top level I have NavigationView. To paint background I am using ZStack. The problem is that when I wrap list in ZStack and scroll it, list items collapse with NavigationView. I can achieve the correct behavior only if the list is direct child of NavView and has no changed background color.
Code:

```
  init() {
        // Title text color
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .clear

        // Clear list background color
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear

        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
    }

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("DarkShade"), Color("PrimaryDark")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                List(self.viewModel.rooms.enumerated().map({ $0 }), id: \.element.id) { (index, room) in
                    ZStack {
                        RoomsItemView(room: room)
                            .onAppear(perform: {
                                let count = self.viewModel.rooms.count

                                if index == count - 1 {
                                    self.viewModel.loadRooms(currentListSize: count)
                                }
                            })

                        NavigationLink(destination: GuestRoomView(room: room)) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                .pullToRefresh(isShowing: self.$isRefreshing, onRefresh: self.onRefresh)
                .navigationBarTitle("rooms_title")
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .navigationBarItems(
                    leading:
                        Button(action: {
                            self.shouldShowSpotifyAuth = false
                        }) {
                            VStack {
                                Spacer()

                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .frame(height: 20.0)

                                    Spacer()
                                }

                                Spacer()
                            }
                                .frame(width: 40.0, height: 30.0)
                    },
                    trailing:
                        Button(action: {
                            print("create room")
                        }) {
                            VStack {
                                Spacer()

                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()

                                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .frame(height: 20.0)
                                }

                                Spacer()
                            }
                                .frame(width: 40.0, height: 30.0)
                    }
                )
        }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                self.onRefresh()
            })
            .onReceive(viewModel.onRoomsUpdate) {
                self.isRefreshing = false
            }
            .gesture(DragGesture().updating($dragOffset, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                        if(value.startLocation.x < 20 && value.translation.width > 100) {
                            self.shouldShowSpotifyAuth = false
                        }
                })
            )
    }
```

Expected result:
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIwTu.png)

Actual result:
[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpZrJ.png)